# sending bulk mails in background and storing response in java web app

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am displaying a list of employees details in a jsp page ,there would be approximately 5000 employees details displayed on the page.

I Have Provided an option like Mail All when the user clicks on Mail All I want to send mails in the background and store it's delivery status, after completion i wish to show the user about the delivery status of Mails How many sent and how many failed.

one of my friend said Threads are the way to go , I wanted to Know the possible ways this can be achieved and a sample code would be great.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. In its current form your question is unanswerable, because it is too broad. Please gather extra information and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27752801/edit) your post.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html

Create a Thread class:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

  @Override
  public void run(){
    System.out.println("MyThread running");
  }
}
```

Run with:

MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
  myTread.start();//to call run() as a new thread

As an upgrade, you could also take a look a ThreadPool, for instance: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html
or Java 7 Fork/Join (Threads that return results, by default), you can start here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/java-forkjoin-parallel-programming.html

Comment: I've implemented this using threads, but I want to achieve this asynchronously and after completion of sending each mails a status should poped at client side

Comment: Threads are async, but are you asking for how to mail? I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: @Danielson: This is why I said in my comment on the question that the question is too broad to be answered. In its current form we can only guess what the OP is looking for.